# Creating multiple spark dataframes in a for loop with different df names

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function that creates a spark dataframe from json stored in AWS S3 and I need to iterate over a list of possible folders inside S3 (Simplified code below).

```
def create_glue_df(table):
    df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"jsonPath": "$._airbyte_data", "multiline": True},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [f"s3://bucketx/raw-data/test/{table}/"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx=f"{table}",
    )
    
    df = df.toDF()
    
    return df
```

Then I have a list of possible tables:

```
table_list = ['orders', 'products', 'price', 'inventory', etc.]
```

I'm trying to create a for loop to iterate over the table list and passing the iterator over the function to create a dataframe for each possible table. Not every client has the same amount of tables, but the names are equal:

```
for table in table_list :
    try:
        df = create_glue_df(table)
        print(f'Table {table} created.')
    except:
        print(f'Table {table} not found.')
```

I already searched in stackoverflow how can I pass an iterator to a variable name, some say using globals() (but not recommend it), other using a dict. But when I tried the dict method, I couldn't get the spark df.

After the iterator, I could access each df with the corresponded suffix:

'orders' would create a df_orders
'products' would create a df_produts

Is there a way that I could achieve this (and not using pandas)?

Answer (score 0):

You want many dataframes.

Store them in a dict.

```
dfs = {}

def create_glue_df(dfs: dict, table: str) -> None:
    ...
    dfs[table] = df.toDF()
    return  # (clearly you don't need this line -- it merely emphasizes that the helper is only invoked for side effects)
```

Comment: I tried this one, but I couldn't acces the content of the dfs.

Comment: If you call `create_glue_df()` a dozen times (with distinct `table` names), you will get a dict with a dozen entries -- `len(dfs) == 12`. Then you can iterate over it, or ask it about a specific dataframe such as `df = dfs['orders']` or `dfs['products']`.